# Doctrine2 :one-to-many relation;

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, doctrine-query

i have 2 entity with one-to-many relation : `Article` & `ArticleCategory`

```
class Article {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rate", type="integer",options={"default" : 0})
 */
 private $rate = 0;
 /**
 * @var \ArticleCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticleCategory",inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $category;
 }


class ArticleCategory {
/**
 *
 * @var \Article 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $articles;
}
```

now i want to fetch categories which has much articles with top rates..

" i mean **top N categories ordered by highest rated article in them** (*categories which has more articles with rate above the average rate*)"

how can i do this?

Comment: you obviously need a rate field in your entity. You should begin by that, then use DQL or criterias to define what is a "top" rate.

Comment: i have `rate` field in my `Article` Entity!see the question again! :)

Comment: Well if you write incomplete code dont expect people to guess for you , there is no annotations for the rate field , so it is not a doctrine orm field to me , as your question stands now.

Comment: What does it mean "fetch categories which has much articles with top rates" ? You meant that you want get for example top N categories ordered by average of all ratings? Or top N categories ordered by highest rated article in them? Or all categories which have top-rated articles (eg. if top rate is 10, you'll get all categories which have an article rated with 10 rate)? Please, precise your question

Comment: @Cyprian, thanks for your comment.i tried to clarify it again,by adding this to my question "i mean top N categories ordered by highest rated article in them (categories which has more articles with rate above the average rate )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found this for my question, maybe it can be useful for others! :)

```
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c, avg(a.rate) x
                               FROM YoutabsGeneralModelBundle:ArticleCategory c 
                               JOIN c.articles a 
                               GROUP BY c.id
                               ORDER BY x DESC');
```

i add `ORDER BY` because i wanted to set limit on this :

```
    $query->setMaxResults($limit);
```